# What is the equivalent code in java for below kotlin code?

Tags: android

Here is the code of send a simple request which I have modified in kotlin, I want its equivalent code in Java. Basically I am not able to understand what `log.d` function does and how to convert `log.d` to java

```
private fun loadMeme () {
        // Instantiate the requestQueue.  
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue (this)
        val url = "https://www.google.com" 

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.  
        val stringRequest =  StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
        {response -> Log.d ("success Request", response.substring (0,500)},
        { Log.d ("error",  Lt. LocalizedMessage })

        // Add the request to the Request
        Queue. Queue.add (stringRequest)
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

```
String Url = "https://www.google.com"

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                 //success response will be here
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                 //error response will be here
                            }
                        }){
                };
        
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(YourActivity.this);
                queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: My success response in kotlin is response ->
                Log.d("success Request",response.substring(0,500)) . How to change it in java?

Comment: its also same for java

Comment: My error response in kotlin is  Log.d("error",it.localizedMessage),but in java its not accepting localizedMessage. So what is its equivalent

Comment: Log.d("error response: ", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getLocalizedMessage()));

Comment: dont use it.localizedMessage 

check your error variable and then use that

Comment: Can you please provide me the references of handling such responses so that i can refer them in near future. Thank you

Comment: Connect me Through facebook or git so that you can contact with me.